# Не выходит из Angular загрузить изображение на сервер nodejs с помощь multer

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

У меня в Ангуляре есть форма с загрузкой файла(изображения), который нужно сохранить в папке на сервере. Но по каким-то причинам у меня этого не выходит, папка куда должны сохраняться изображения создалась, а вот изображения туда не сохраняются. Ошибок никаких не выдает

**Моя форма в файле *dashboard.component.html***

```
<form action="setProfileImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input hidden="true" type="file" name="filedata" id="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
    <label for="file-input">
        <div mat-raised-button class="btn" class="userInfo__addFoto">
            <p>Завантажити фото</p>
        </div>
    </label>
</form>
```

***dashboard.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'flash-messages-angular';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile!: File;
  userId=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  constructor(
    private flashMessages: FlashMessagesService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filedata',this.selectedFile);
    console.log(formData);
    this.authService.setImage(formData);
  }

}
```

**Функция в *auth.service.ts***

```
  setImage(data: any) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/account/setProfileImage',
    data);
  }
```

**Часть из кода отвечающая за этот функционал на сервере *node.js***

```
const upload = multer({dest:"uploads"});

router.post('/setProfileImage', upload.single("filedata"), (req, res) => {
    
    filedata = req.file;
 
    console.log(filedata);
    if(!filedata)
        res.send("Ошибка при загрузке файла");
    else
        res.send("Файл загружен");
});
```

Comment: Выгладит вроде нормально. А ваши 2 лога что пишут?

Comment: Единственное, не понятно, в каком месте вы получаете ответ на клиенте